# IsSerializable returning "false" for an object marked Serializable

Tags: c#, .net, serializable

I'm attempting to serialize a DenseMatrix object which is an object provided within the MathNET Numerics project.

[DenseMatrix.cs](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0c1b688a62b2#src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Double/DenseMatrix.cs)

Below I have provided some useful information.

- I can see from both the object explorer as well as .NET reflector that this class (and everything this class inherits from) is marked as [Serializable].
- Attribute.IsDefined(typeof(MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.DenseMatrix), typeof(SerializedAttribute)) returns **true**.
- typeof(MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.DenseMatrix).IsSerializable returns **false**
- It seems everything in the Mathnet.Numerics Matrix family is marked [Serializable], though they all show the same non-serializable behavior.

Now, when I attempt to run my object through a BinaryFormatter, I get a SerializationException "Type MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.DenseMatrix is not marked as Serializable".

What is going on here? I know that the BinaryFormatter is looking directly at the IsSerializable property, so that's why it's coughing up. So why is IsSerializable returning false?

**EDIT**

The question is directed more toward the .NET implementation of IsSerializable in general, and only uses The Mathnet example as context.

**2nd EDIT**

I think adding to the confusion was the fact that I was using MathNet's "portable" library version.  In order to make the portable library compile, they had created a custom SerializableAttribute that would be used since System.SerializableAttribute is not available for a portable library.  When running with Mono, System.Type would look for System.SerializableAttribute, but only find MathNet.SerializableAttribute.

Comment: You already filed a bug report, you know that the problem is that the Storage classes are not serializable.  You can wait or you can fix it yourself.

Comment: The question is not specific to Mathnet, it is specific to why the IsSerializable property on Type does not return true for an object marked Serializable.

If attributes don't provide any type safety, and  if they don't yield objects that can be serialized, then what is the point?

Comment: Do you have multiple copies of the assembly on the affected machine/environment?

Comment: I tried, it returned true.  In general, attributes have nothing to do with type safety, they are just metadata.  The [Serializable] attribute means nothing more than "it's okay to mess with my private parts".  That the object can't actually be serialized is just a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET recursively checks all members of objects marked [Serializable], and IsSerializable returns false if the types of any members of a [Serializable] class are not marked [Serializable] as well.

The solution to the above case is to simply mark the classes that are members in DenseMatrix as [Serializable].

i.e.
DenseColumnMatrixStorage

MatrixStorage